# using log rotator in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cron-task, laravel-5

Consider the following:

This is a conf file, in: `conf/log_rotation/laravel_rotate.conf`

```
storage/logs/laravel.log {
  missingok
  notifempty
  compress
  size 1024k
  daily
  create 0640
}
```

Is triggered by this laravel task run daily:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Logrotater extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'log_rotater';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Rotates the logs on an hourly basis';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        exec("logrotate -f config/log_rotation/tweet_rotate.conf");
        exec("logrotate -f config/log_rotation/laravel_rotate.conf");
    }
}
```

When I do: `php artisan log_rotater` I get:

```
error: config/log_rotation/laravel_rotate.conf:1 unknown option 'storage' -- ignoring line
error: config/log_rotation/laravel_rotate.conf:8 unexpected }
```

**Ideas as to why I am getting this error?**

Answer (score 1):

**logrotate** requires path provided to be absolute, otherwise it treats given string as configuration option. That's why you're getting **unknown option storage** error.

Replace

```
storage/logs/laravel.log
```

with the absolute path.